# Squid Proxy Very Slow Causing Timeout

Tags: proxy, squid

I have just installed the [Squid proxy server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html.en) on a Raspberry Pi ([Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/)).

I am trying to connect to it via Firefox. I have made the following proxy settings (dummy IP below obviously):

[image: Firefox proxy settings]

It connects but it's extremely slow, to the point that most of the times I just get a timeout screen in Firefox:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Note: the only change I made is `http_access deny all` -> `http_access allow all`

Answer (score 9):

After about an hour of digging I found [this thread](https://www.clearos.com/clearfoundation/social/community/squid-running-really-slow), where one of the users had the solution:

1. Open the Squid config file: `sudo vim /etc/squid/squid.conf`
2. Navigate to the bottom of the config file: `Shift + G` if using vim
3. Insert this code on a new line (press i if using vim): `dns_v4_first on`
4. Save the file: (`esc` then type `:wq` then `enter`) if using vim
5. Restart Squid: `sudo systemctl restart squid`

Note: that setting is already in there somewhere but commented so if you prefer you can search for it and uncomment it.

Comment: What this does, it forces squid to only use ipv4 and avoid timeouts trying ipv6. And people ask why ipv4 is so popular.... Thanks, this was very helpful!!

Comment: I can't believe it. I was having this issue, found many ppl with it and all suggesting tests to do on server and browser. When I force it to use IPv4, it works!